# "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" creating new worksheet

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I actually wrote this over a month ago in preparation for a project, and I had it working. Now I get this error and cannot figure out why its being thrown. I even created a folder and checked the permissions on it. Any suggestions?

```
namespace E_Report
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application xlApp = new Application();
            Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("Report.xlsx");
            Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlApp.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1"); // Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

            xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Account Number";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Amount";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Code";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Date";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Audit";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 6] = "ID";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Customer Name";
            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Payment Source";

            xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\Report.xlsx");

            xlApp.Quit();

            xlWorkbook.Close(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have any additional information regarding the exception? A StackTrace or any other information besides an error code would be helpful.

Comment: I step through it in the debugger, and under value I see System_ComObject for the workbook and for the sheet I see null, nothing else though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `xlApp.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")` you're trying to **add a new worksheet before** `Sheet1`, it expects an existing `Worksheet` object (and `0x800A03EC` is `NAME_NOT_FOUND`).

I suppose what you're trying to do is to add a **new sheet named** `Sheet1`:

```
 Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlApp.Worksheets.Add();
xlWorksheet.Name = "Sheet1";
```

Now also the line `xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");`
 can be simply dropped.

Comment: Well I was trying to put headers into the first sheet yes.

Comment: Then you don't need that parameter (see MSDN, it's to insert the new sheet before an existing one). Also the other line can be dropped